Time reverse of circular polarization
I have a simple question regarding time-reversal operation on circular polarization.
If there is an right-handed circular polarization (RCP), the time reversal operation will give LCP. And i dont understand this point.
Assume that the RCP light is propagating along positive z-direction. Here the electric field is rotating CCW on x-y plane from the view point of the observer located at positive z.
But if time reversal operation is applied,

the direction (k) will  be opposite. namely, the observer now should be located at negative $z$.

the direction of rotation is changed.


Hence, the new observer located at negative $z$ feel same type of circular polarization.
What am I wrong?

Do you have a citation for the statement that $T$ reverses circular polarization? Your argument that helicity is preserved under $T$ (currently expanded in an answer) seems sound.

@rob here is what brings my question up: https://doi.org/10.1038/s44310-024-00018-5. In short, to satisfy their argument, time reverse of LCP should be RCP for symmetry in photonic crystal

We use a photon instead of a plane wave. It has a momentum $\vec p=\hbar \vec k$, a spin $\vec\sigma$, and a helicity:
$$ h = \vec{\sigma}\cdot\vec p$$
and it is helicity, not spin, that we associate with circular polarization.
With that:
$$ T:\vec p \rightarrow -\vec p$$
$$ T:\vec{\sigma} \rightarrow -\vec{\sigma}$$
$$ T: h \rightarrow +h $$
which just confirms your point.
Likewise, if we use fields:
$$ T: \vec E \rightarrow +\vec E $$
$$ T: \vec B \rightarrow -\vec B $$
$$ T: \vec S \rightarrow -\vec S $$
$$ T \vec k \rightarrow -\vec k $$
with $\vec S = \vec E \times \vec B$. Which doesn't help.
It may come down to the phase between $E_x$ and $E_y$, since LHCP:

has an electric field:
$$ \vec E = (\cos k(ct-z), -\sin k(ct-z), 0 ) $$
which transforms to:
$$ T\vec E = (\cos k(ct+z), \sin k(ct+z), 0 ) $$
which moves in the opposite direction an has flipped $E_y$.
Now I got that from wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_polarization), which has a
good discussion of the the two conventions for defining polarization (from the view of the source, or from the view of the receiver).
I don't thing the position of the receiver is transformed by $T$, so it's looking at the wave from behind...reversing the sign of CP. Wiki states:
Uses of the two conventions
As stated earlier, there is significant confusion with regards to these two conventions. As a general rule, the engineering, quantum physics, and radio astronomy communities use the first convention, in which the wave is observed from the point of view of the source.In many physics textbooks dealing with optics, the second convention is used, in which the light is observed from the point of view of the receiver.
To avoid confusion, it is good practice to specify "as defined from the point of view of the source" or "as defined from the point of view of the receiver" when discussing polarization matters.
The archive of the US Federal Standard 1037C proposes two contradictory conventions of handedness.
So maybe that's it?

Re "I don't think the position of the receiver is transformed by T": time reversal swaps the roles of the emitter and the receiver.

@rob well I find that more confusing, since if the source is at $(0,0,0)$ and the receiver is at $(0,0,Z)$ seeing a wave with $(0,0,k)$, then under $T$: the Rx (I worked in radar, I can't help it)  is now at $(0,0,0)$ and the Tx is at $(0,0,Z)$ and the wave is $k=(0,0,-k)$, but only exists at $z \le 0$, so it doesn't touch the source. Does that make sense?

I don't understand why you put the time-reversed wave in a different position. Suppose that in the first case the photon travels from $(z,t)=(0,0)$ to $(+cT,+T)$ with momentum $+k$. Reverse the time coordinate and the photon travels from $(+cT,-T)$ to $(0,0)$ with momentum $-k$.

@rob yup, you're right. I'm not sure I learned to apply $T$ to whole systems, just particles and equations.

I think you are right to conclude that the circular polarisation would not be reversed by time reversal. One conventional and consistent way of defining circular polarisation is the right hand rule. If the thumb of your right hand points in the direction of the wave propagation and the rotation is in the direction that your fingers curl when closing your hand, it is called right handed circular polarisation. If we have a video of the wave and play it in reverse, the rotation direction will change, but so will the direction of propagation, so the wave still has right handed circular polarisation.

hmm... then how can I connect this analogy(LCP -> LCP) to quantum-mechanical perspective(LCP -> RCP). It seems like a condtradiction

Have you got a formal reference for quantum-mechanical perspective(LCP -> RCP). ? Time reversal is hypothetical because no one has ever managed to reverse time and measure the results in a lab. Does your source have a clear definition of the helicity of a circularly polarised photon?
